# How to pad an array of images with a given color without a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I have a numpy array of images that contains numpy arrays of images and I'm trying to pad each image in the array with a given color without using a for loop. In other words, I want everything vectorized.

For producing the error: uncomment the commented line and comment the one below it, you'll get ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (3,) and requested shape (4,2)

You can use this image for testing.

[image: Tiger]

**Here is what I did:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def pad_image(image, pad_width, values, mode='img_arr'):
    """
    Add a pad(border) of a given width and value to the image.
    Args:
        image: Image array or a single image.
        pad_width: The width of the pad.
        values: Value of the pad layer.
        mode: A string representation of the input
            'img_arr': Array of images.
            'img': A single image.

    Return:
        numpy array of padded images or a padded image.
    """
    if mode == 'img_arr':
        # The following commented line will give an error if constant_values is an RGB tuple.
        # return np.pad(
        #     image, ((0, 0), (pad_width, pad_width), (pad_width, pad_width), (0, 0)), constant_values=values)
        return np.array([cv2.copyMakeBorder(
            img, pad_width, pad_width, pad_width, pad_width, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=values)
            for img in image])
    if mode == 'img':
        return cv2.copyMakeBorder(
            image, pad_width, pad_width, pad_width, pad_width, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=values)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tiger = cv2.imread('tiger.jpeg')
    tiger_arr_test = np.array([tiger for i in range(1000)])
    pad_width = 5
    color = (255, 0, 0)
    padded_arr = pad_image(tiger_arr_test, pad_width, color)
    plt.imshow(padded_arr[0])
    plt.title(f'First padded image of the array of images.')
    plt.show()
    padded_single = pad_image(tiger, pad_width, color, 'img')
    print(padded_single.shape)
    plt.imshow(padded_single)
    plt.title('Padded single image.')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What went wrong?

Comment: @wwii As I want to get rid of the for loop uncomment the commented line and comment the one below it, you'll get ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (3,) and requested shape (4,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it without using `numpy.pad`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
tiger = cv2.imread('tiger.jpg')
tigers = np.array((tiger,tiger,tiger,tiger,tiger))

color = np.array((255, 0, 0))
pad = 5
sub = slice(pad,-pad)
```

Make an array of the border color using the shape of the original

```
z,a,b,c = tigers.shape
newshape = (z, pad+a+pad, pad+b+pad, c)
w = np.zeros(newshape,dtype=np.uint8) + color
```

Then just assign the original array to the middle of the new array

```
w[:,sub,sub,:] = tigers

plt.imshow(w[3])
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

---

Using `numpy.pad` - pad with zero then assign the color to the four edges

```
q = np.pad(tigers,((0,0),(pad,pad),(pad,pad),(0,0)))
q[:,:,:5,:] = color
q[:,:,-5:,:] = color
q[:,:5,:,:] = color
q[:,-5:,:,:] = color
```

`numpy.pad` and assign the color using a boolean mask

```
q = np.pad(tigers,((0,0),(pad,pad),(pad,pad),(0,0)))
mask = np.ones(q.shape[:-1],dtype=np.bool8)
mask[:,sub,sub] = False
q[mask] = color
```